# ansible docker container - Restart = always in docker_service?

Tags: docker, ansible

I have a RPi where docker does not restart when the RPi reboots with `docker_service`.

In docker_service, it seams to get same as  the documented way is:

```
docker_service:
  project_name: myprj
  definition: 
    version: 2
    services:
      mariadb:
        image: ...
      nrc101:
        image: ...
        depends_on: 
          - mariadb
  restarted: yes
  state: present
```

However, this does not restart when the RPi restarts, say on power failure.

Where-as the `ansible docker_container` has a `restart_policy: always` declaration that does work. Now, I want to use the `docker_service` and not `docker_container` as I have containers dependent on one another, not sure how to do this in `docker_service`, as the documentation way does not work.

Does anyone know how to restart containers using `docker_service`?

Comment: What is “*the documentation way [that] does not work*”? Where did you specify restart policy? Why isn’t it in the question?

Comment: ansible `docker_service` - per my understanding, only has `restarted: yes, and state: present`, where-as ansible `docker_container` has a `restart_policy` construct. So, can one not do restarts of docker with `docker_service`? Sorry, does this answer your question? Should I put url's to the `documented way` as I have it?

Comment: Did you read the meaning of `restarted` parameter in the documentation (which you refer to)?

Comment: Hi techraf, I assume you refer to http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/docker_service_module.html, yes, if I understand it correctly, that is why I use `restarted: yes` with `state: present`. But this does not give me a container on reboot of the host. Am I looking it wrong?

Comment: `Use with state present to restart all containers.` – "to restart" is not "to define restart policy".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this in your `docker_container` task:

```yaml
- name: Create Prometheus docker container
  docker_container:
    name: Prometheus
    image: prom/prometheus
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - /etc/docker/prometheus:/etc/prometheus
    state: started
    restart: yes
    restart_policy: "always"
```

The last line, `restart_policy: "always"`, is what you need. More options and info here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_container_module.html#parameter-restart_policy

Answer (score 2):

**What your code does now**

- It defines an inline docker-compose in `definition`.
- It restarts all containers per `restarted` parameter.

---

**What you specify you want to do**

- You want to specify a restart policy.

---

You specify the restart policy **in the docker-compose** file, so head to [the Docker Compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/) and search for "restart policy".

Then define:

```
restart: always
```

for each container.

Comment: But I am not using a docker-compose file, I do the definition of statements as it was supposed to be in docker-compose inside the playbook (not showing all steps in my example). Maybe the problem is with `definition`, looks like I am using it incorrectly, testing without it now...

Comment: Please **do read the docs** before discussing things. And also do read the answer before commenting.

Comment: sho!, thanks, I did not know that one can use docker-compose constructs inside a ansible playbook, inside a service. your suggestion of using `restart: yes` inside ea. container worked, (inside the ansible playbook for ea docker_service), this I did not understand in the ansible `docker_service` documentation. This opens a new world to me !